# OpenProcess with PROCESS_DUP_HANDLE access right

Tags: windows, security, winapi

Is it possible to get any kind of information or access to a process from handle returned by `OpenProcess` function with `PROCESS_DUP_HANDLE` access right, **not using** function  `DuplicateHandle` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`PROCESS_DUP_HANDLE` (0x0040) lets you duplicate handles out of the target process (i.e. allows you to call [`DuplicateHandle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724251.aspx) on a handle from that process). To get "information" out of the process, you typically want:

- `PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION` (0x0400) or
- `PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION` (0x1000)

Which `PROCESS_DUP_HANDLE` (by itself) doesn't grant.

This page provides basic info on the various [access flags](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684880.aspx).

EDIT:

> by malicious I mean to break confidentiality, integrity or availability of the process.

No, with only `PROCESS_DUP_HANDLE` rights, you will not be able to do anything malicious with the process. ReadProcessMemory, VirtualAllocEx, TerminateProcess, etc. will all return ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED.

But, if you are running code on the same box, then you *can* be malicious by other means. Consuming all free memory or hard disk space, raising your own process to real-time and consuming the CPU, etc.

Comment: actually I've asked this question from a security perspective, i.e. is it possible to get any info or access to a process that you are not allowed/supposed to get, if you are able to call **only** `OpenProcess` with `PROCESS_DUP_HANDLE`, and you are **not** able to call `DuplicateHandle`. So you have only handle returned by `OpenProcess` with `PROCESS_DUP_HANDLE` access right, can you do anything with this handle to do something malicious with the process?

Comment: by *malicious* I mean to break *confidentiality*, *integrity* or *availability* of the process.

Comment: @William, edited the post to add information about malicious uses.

Comment: @joshpoley I am not sure I agree that you can't do anything malicious with the PROCESS_DUP_HANDLE.  I came across this question doing similar research and I do not think it is a good idea to give an untrusted process a process handle with this access right as they can gain access to any open file objects or pipes.

Edit: I guess the question being asked initially is a bit more narrow but the security hole still remains.